# Monaco Editor reveal all lines

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, editor, monaco-editor

I'm using [Microsoft's Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index.html) library to create a code editor on a webpage and it's great, but as it seems, for performance reasons, only the visible lines are actually rendered, which does not sound like a problem it actually is when you want to print the contents of the editor.

Is there a way I could force the rendering of all lines?

My best guess was

```
editor.revealRange
```

and other `editor.reveal*` methods, but none of that seem to work.

Comment: You will have more answers here: https://superuser.com

Comment: Hey, maybe I was not clear enough - Monaco Editor is a library/component that can be embedded on a web page. So it's actually more of a programming related question.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The `reveal` methods exist to scroll the editor to a specific position. Instead you can just get the full content of the model and print that:

```js
const content = editor.getModel().getValue();
```

However, this returns only the raw text, no syntax colors.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to the top, run

```js
HTMLDivElement.prototype.removeChild=function(){}
```

then scroll to the bottom. Voilà, all the lines are rendered.
Some even twice, but that's ok since they're positioned absolute.

You could try to avoid duplicates via

```js
HTMLDivElement.prototype.reallyRemoveChild=HTMLDivElement.prototype.removeChild;
HTMLDivElement.prototype.removeChild=function(el){
    if(el.parentElement.querySelectorAll(`[style="${el.getAttribute('style')}"]`).length === 2)
    this.reallyRemoveChild.apply(this, arguments)
};
```